# float required?? Error with round() in Python

Tags: python, rounding

could not find this question answered by search. I am trying to learn some Python and need your help this this function:

```
def roundtest():
    i = round(raw_input("call a number: "), 2)
    print i
```

My input & the error I get:

```
call a number: 1.2222

TypeError: a float is required
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, which you then have to parse in to a `float`, like so:

```
def roundtest():
    i = round(float(raw_input("call a number: ")), 2)
    print i
```

Comment: @bermudaa make sure you accept the answer to indicate it was helpful to other readers.